# Keep largest duplicate value in list based on a particular member value

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I have this list and I am trying to

- only keep one item for every unique item[0] and
- the one item kept must have the highest value in item[3]
  For example, the `item[0]` [832] is repeated multiple times in the list `([832], ['G'], ['A'], [39]),  ([832], ['G'], ['A'], [40]), ([832], ['G'], ['A'], [40]), ([832], ['G'], ['A'], [38]), ([832], ['G'], ['A'], [39]), ([832], ['G'], ['A'], [40]), ([832], ['G'], ['A'], [40]), ([832], ['G'], ['A'], [40])`

I would like to only keep one `([832], ['G'], ['A'], [40])` value as it has the largest `item[3]`

For the case `([2792, 2810], ['C', 'C'], ['T', 'T'], [40, 40])` I would like to treat it as two separate cases `([2792], ['C'], ['T'], [40, 40])` and `([2810], ['C'], ['T'], [40])`

my list:

```
[([832], ['G'], ['A'], [39]), ([2792], ['C'], ['T'], [39]), ([2810], ['C'], ['T'], [40]), ([586], ['G'], ['A'], [40]), ([586], ['G'], ['A'], [40]), ([832], ['G'], ['A'], [40]), ([2810], ['C'], ['T'], [40]), ([2792, 2810], ['C', 'C'], ['T', 'T'], [40, 40]), ([2730], ['A'], ['G'], [40]), ([4623, 4624], ['A', 'T'], ['G', 'C'], [29, 12]), ([2810], ['C'], ['T'], [40]), ([4687], ['T'], ['G'], [22]), ([2730], ['A'], ['G'], [40]), ([3493], ['G'], ['T'], [40]), ([2730], ['A'], ['G'], [40]), ([2810], ['C'], ['T'], [40]), ([832], ['G'], ['A'], [40]), ([444, 471], ['A', 'A'], ['T', 'T'], [10, 15]), ([2730], ['A'], ['G'], [40]), ([784], ['T'], ['A'], [27]), ([2730], ['A'], ['G'], [40]), ([2730], ['A'], ['G'], [40]), ([2792, 2810], ['C', 'C'], ['T', 'T'], [40, 40]), ([5373], ['T'], ['C'], [31]), ([3131], ['G'], ['A'], [40]), ([2730], ['A'], ['G'], [40]), ([2810], ['C'], ['T'], [40]), ([2792, 2810], ['C', 'C'], ['T', 'T'], [40, 40]), ([586], ['G'], ['A'], [40]), ([3578], ['A'], ['T'], [40]), ([2810], ['C'], ['T'], [40]), ([2730], ['A'], ['G'], [39]), ([832], ['G'], ['A'], [40]), ([2810], ['C'], ['T'], [40]), ([832], ['G'], ['A'], [38]), ([4248], ['T'], ['A'], [33]), ([832], ['G'], ['A'], [39]), ([2792], ['C'], ['T'], [40]), ([586], ['G'], ['A'], [40]), ([832], ['G'], ['A'], [40]), ([2730], ['A'], ['G'], [40]), ([2730], ['A'], ['G'], [40]), ([2730], ['A'], ['G'], [38]), ([2810], ['C'], ['T'], [40]), ([832], ['G'], ['A'], [40]), ([2730], ['A'], ['G'], [37]), ([4146, 4173], ['A', 'T'], ['T', 'G'], [33, 9]), ([99, 103], ['A', 'A'], ['C', 'C'], [24, 28]), ([99, 108], ['A', 'A'], ['C', 'C'], [19, 28]), ([882], ['T'], ['A'], [40]), ([2663], ['T'], ['A'], [23]), ([832], ['G'], ['A'], [40]), ([2792], ['C'], ['T'], [40])]
```

Comment: What exactly was the problem when you tried to do it?

Comment: What if there are multiple items that have the same highest value in that position? Also, does the order of the output list matter?

Comment: @tobias_k then we print out all the items! say `([832], ['G'], ['A'], [40]), ([2810], ['C'], ['T'], [40])` both has 40 in it, I would keep both since their first item is different!

Comment: im just trying to get rid of items that have the same first item, say `([832], ['G'], ['A'], [39]), ([832], ['G'], ['A'], [40]).` then I would keep  `([832], ['G'], ['A'], [40])` since it has a higher value in  item[3]

Comment: please let me know if this is still unclear!

Comment: @mkrieger1 my problem is that I don't exactly know how to approach this... i did `list.sort(key=lambda x: x[3], reverse = True)` but it only gives one output which is `([2792, 2810], ['C', 'C'], ['T', 'T'], [40, 40])`

Comment: @mkrieger1 hence I have trouble filtering out duplicate values for item[0] based on the values in item[3]

Comment: I was referring to elements where the first items is the same and the last is the same highest value.

Comment: @tobias_k ah i see, then we would just have to keep either one!

Answer (score 2):

Since your own approach involved sorting the list, I assume that the order of the result list is not important. In this case, you can use e.g. a `dict` to map the key element to the item with the max value in index 3, and then just get the `values` from that dictionary.

```
max_v = {}
for t in lst:
    k = tuple(t[0])
    if k not in max_v or t[3] > max_v[k][3]:
        max_v[k] = t

res = list(max_v.values())
```

If order is important, then you could still use that as a preprocessing step, and then get only those elements from the list (in their original order) that match the value for their respective key in the dictionary. Since there are also *exact* duplicate elements, you will have to `pop` them from the `dict` as you go (or filter out the dupes first, but that's more involved since the items are not hashable).

```
res2 = [max_v.pop(tuple(t[0])) for t in lst if t == max_v.get(tuple(t[0]))]
```

Or another kind of sneaky way: Since `dict` preserves insertion order in newer version of Python, you could `del` the item from the dict if they are already in there, so a new item is inserted instead of replacing the old one, i.e.:

```
    if k not in max_v or t[3] > max_v[k][3]:
        if k in max_v:
            del max_v[k]
        max_v[k] = t
```